# Postgres crashed when I run function

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.2

I would like to copy part of one geography table (hidrography) to another table. So I did one functions to help me it. However everytime I ran it the postgres (see figure above).

Why my query didn't continue to run?

Here is the data that I have used (database). 
ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/cartas_e_mapas/bases_cartograficas_continuas/bc250/versao2015/postgis/

```
-- Function: public.testediogo1(integer)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.testediogo1(integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.testediogo1(p_passo integer)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    tabela text;
    passo integer;
    total integer;
    counter integer;
    counter_loop integer;
    counter_insert integer;
    curs refcursor;
    rec record; 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM bc250_ba.hid_trecho_drenagem_l_ba;
    passo := p_passo;
    SELECT INTO total MAX(id_objeto) FROM bc250.hid_trecho_drenagem_l;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Total: %', total;
    counter := 0;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Total: %', counter;
    counter_loop := 0;
    counter_insert := 0;
    WHILE counter < total
    --FOR counter IN 1..round(total/passo)
    --RAISE NOTICE 'Entrando no while: %' counter;          
    LOOP

    counter_loop := counter_loop + 1;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Entrando no loop: %', counter_loop;
        OPEN curs FOR SELECT 
                htd.nome,
                htd.nomeabrev,
                htd.geometriaaproximada,
                htd.dentrodepoligono,
                htd.compartilhado,
                htd.caladomax,
                htd.larguramedia,
                htd.velocidademedcorrente,
                htd.profundidademedia,
                htd.coincidecomdentrode,
                htd.navegabilidade,
                htd.regime,
                htd.geom,
                htd.id_objeto
            FROM (
                SELECT nome, geom 
                FROM bc250.lim_unidade_federacao_a
                WHERE nome = 'Bahia') AS ba,
                bc250.hid_trecho_drenagem_l as htd 
            WHERE        
                htd.id_objeto >= (counter) AND htd.id_objeto <= (counter + passo) AND ST_Intersects(ba.geom, htd.geom);
                --htd.id_objeto >= 6175078 AND htd.id_objeto <=  6185078 AND ST_Intersects(ba.geom, htd.geom);
                --ORDER BY htd.id_objeto ASC;

        counter := counter + passo;
        RAISE NOTICE 'cursor aberto: %', counter_loop;      
        LOOP
            FETCH NEXT IN curs INTO rec;
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
            counter_insert = counter_insert + 1;
            RAISE NOTICE 'fazendo insert: %', counter_insert;
            INSERT INTO bc250_ba.hid_trecho_drenagem_l_ba (
                                    nome,
                                    nomeabrev,
                                    geometriaaproximada,
                                    dentrodepoligono,
                                    compartilhado,
                                    caladomax,
                                    larguramedia,
                                    velocidademedcorrente,
                                    profundidademedia,
                                    coincidecomdentrode,
                                    navegabilidade,
                                    regime,
                                    geom,
                                    id_objeto_hid_250
                                    )
                                 VALUES(
                                    rec.nome,
                                    rec.nomeabrev,
                                    rec.geometriaaproximada,
                                    rec.dentrodepoligono,
                                    rec.compartilhado,
                                    rec.caladomax,
                                    rec.larguramedia,
                                    rec.velocidademedcorrente,
                                    rec.profundidademedia,
                                    rec.coincidecomdentrode,
                                    rec.navegabilidade,
                                    rec.regime,
                                    rec.geom,
                                    rec.id_objeto);
        END LOOP;                           
        CLOSE curs;
        RAISE NOTICE 'htd.id_objeto >= %', (counter);
        RAISE NOTICE 'htd.id_objeto <=  %', (counter + passo);
    END LOOP;
RETURN 'Sucesso'::text;
END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.testediogo1(integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

[image: The query stopped when I run the function]

Answer (score 2):

Why write a complicated and fragile function? Normally you'd write an SQL statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO bc250_ba.hid_trecho_drenagem_l_ba(nome, geom, ...)
SELECT htd.nome, htd.geom, ...
FROM hid_trecho_drenagem_l AS htd
JOIN lim_unidade_federacao_a AS ba ON ba.nome='Bahia' AND ST_Intersects(ba.geom, htd.geom);
```

which selects the source data from the joined tables, and inserts the result in the other. You can preview the data beforehand by running everything but the first line (i.e. don't INSERT).

Comment: I wrote a query as you said me however the table bc250_ba.hid_trecho_drenagem_l_ba has 1600000 registers and time was so long and a problem happened too. So I did a loop to divide the table in order to reach the all inserts that I need.

Comment: The INSERT INTO approach should still be faster than a custom function, and far easier to troubleshoot. Do you have spatial indexes on the tables you are joining? Try dropping the indexes on hid_trecho_drenagem_l_ba as well, and recreating them after.